# Bitmap pixel replacement based on brightness

Tags: c#, image-processing

Simply, I want to set any pixel in an image to white where the brightness is greater than a given threshold. I have written the following code which works suitably fast and accurately for my purposes.

```
using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap("C:\\temp\\test1.png"))
{
    for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
        {
            Color c = image.GetPixel(x, y);
            float f = c.GetBrightness(); //From 0 (black) to 1 (white)

            if (f > 0.1) { image.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White); }
        }
    }

    image.Save("C:\\temp\\test2.png");
}
```

**However, it just feels wrong to have to loop through every pixel one-by-one. Is there an optimized approach to this problem using another .NET Imaging or Graphics approach?**

Comment: ColorMatrix won't work for this kind of non-linear transform.  Good for contrast changes, not for thresholding.  OpenCV tends to be used for this, the .NET wrapper is called Emgu.  Bit of a cannon vs mosquito approach.

Comment: @Hans - thanks for the Emgu mention - I've never heard of it before and the wrapper for Tesseract OCR is a gem for another project I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some special cases (such as power of 2 thresholds), you can work on 32-bit chunks using bitmasking tricks, but I doubt it would buy you very much.  The far bigger overhead in the code you provided are the `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` calls, which are very inefficient.  You can greatly speed up the procedure using the [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) method and processing the underlying data directly from a `byte[]`.

Comment: Yep.  Check out this code for manipulating bitmaps I grabbed it from somewhere years ago and still use it. [Download](http://www.codingforkinect.com/downloads/FastPixel.rar)

Answer (score 3):

You might optimize by using proven native algorithm implementations (e.g. OpenCV). Although I'm not an expert on this subject, think you will need to iterate through all pixels anyway. Even scientific papers about thresholding algorithms (which rather focus on finding a good threshold) loop through the whole image, so I don't think you have to feel wrong about.

Anyway, if there's some mathematical approach that works on **any** image, I would also be interested, but I doubt the existence.

Answer (score 2):

Consider it this way, if you want to know if a pixel is above or below the threshold for all the pixels, you are going to have to visit all the pixels. Any pixel not visited will mean you don't know its value.

There is no way to write this in better than O(n) time, especially if you intend to change values of certain pixels.

Comment: Agreed.  Only other possibility would be to not open the image as a Bitmap but read the bytes into an array and apply bitwise operations on each set of pixels to determine and set the color to white.  A little overkill for what you are trying to accomplish and would require a lot more time than you should spend on this task :)